# Multisite: Share users and user roles for existing set up

Tags: database, multi-sites

I have made a Drupal 7 multi-site with 3 sites. Each site is running of the same Drupal install and has a separate database.
The database names are `myhost_site1`, `myhost_site2` and `myhost_site 3`.  (My hosting provider puts in the `myhost_` automatically).

I need the 3 sites to share the users and user roles.  I have read various tutorials and these are the steps I have followed:

1. Created a new database called `myhost_users`.
2. Copied the following tables from `myhost_site1` TO `myhost_users`:
   `users`, `user_roles`, `authmap` and `sessions`
3. Given the database users for each of 3 main databases access to `myhost_users`.
4. Open the settings.php for each site and insert the following code (replacing the existing $databse definition):

   ```
   $databases['default']['default'] = array(
     'driver' => 'mysql',      
     'database' => 'NAME OF DATABASE',
     'username' => 'DATABASE USER',
     'password' => 'DATABASE PASSWORD',
     'host' => 'localhost',
     'prefix' => array(
       'default'   => 'NAME OF DATABASE',
       'users'     => 'myhost_users',
       'sessions'  => 'myhost_users',
       'role'      => 'myhost_users',
       'authmap'   => 'myhost_users',
     ),
     'collation' => 'utf8_general_ci',
   ```

   );
5. When I go to my site, I get the following error message:

   > Uncaught exception thrown in session handler. PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
6. For the code posted in (4) I have tried using an underscore suffix for the database names (e.g, `myhost_users_`), but I still get an error message.

What am I doing wrong? Do I need any settings in sites/sites.php?

I would be open to using a module to do this.

[Bakery](https://www.drupal.org/project/bakery) is no good as it doesn't share user roles.

[Account Sync](https://www.drupal.org/project/account_sync) shares roles, but it doesn't  seem to work.

[CAS](https://www.drupal.org/project/cas) requires phpCAS which I do not have access to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need additional modules to achieve what you want.

First: Fix you configuration:

```
'prefix' => array(
'default'   => 'default_db.',
'users'     => 'myhost_users.', //
'sessions'  => 'myhost_users.',
'role'      => 'myhost_users.',
'authmap'   => 'myhost_users.',
),
```

The dots on the end of `'users' => 'myhost_users.'` tells Drupal to query the `users` table in `myhost_users` data base (SQL syntax); without dots you'll get an error like "Base table or view not found `myhost_usersusers`/`myhost_users_users` or similar.

Now,

```
'database' => 'db',
'username' => 'db_user',
'password' => 'db_user_pass',
```

are credentials for the default db where Drupal is installed. To query users db you need to add this user with his password (`db_user`, `db_user_pass`) to the `myhost_users` database. in other words, if you have a site with 2 subsites:

- `myhost_site1` - user of this db
- `myhost_site2` - user of this db
- `myhost_users` - (assuming this db stores Drupal users, that you want to share across ites) user of this sb + user of `myhost_site1` and user of `myhost_site2`

To stay logged in on each site it is necessary to share cookies between sites: edit `settings.php` file of each site, uncomment the line with `# $cookie_domain = '.example.com';` and replace `'.example.com'` with your domain. Don't forget the dot at the beginning (`'.mysite.com'`) -- without it both `mysite.com` and `notmysite.com` could be treated as the same domain.

Comment: Thanks, this works. Except the user doesn't stay logged on between the different sites. I thought sharing authmap would allow for this. How can I make the login stay between the sites.

Comment: Now you need to share cookies between sites: edit `settings.php` for each site, uncomment the line `# $cookie_domain = '.example.com';` and replace `'.example.com'` with your domain. Do not forget the dot at the beggining (`$cookie_domain = '.mydoamin.com';` not `# $cookie_domain = 'mydomain.com';`)!

Comment: Thanks, just to double check: For the shared user db, are `users`, `user_roles`, `authmap` and `sessions` the correct tables to copy into it? Are they too many tables or do I need to copy in other ones? (My main purpose is to share users, roles and loggedin status).

Comment: The tables `user`, `authmap` and `sessions` are necessary to share users between sites. The `users_roles` table should be shared if you want to assign users to their roles across all sites (your case), so if one user has to have different roles in each of your sites the don't share the `users_roles` table.